Capture error message when trapping error in zsh script
I have a zsh script that rarely crashes with no errors showing in the log.  Normally error messages appear.  I'm working on a small test script and learning about trapping.
I want to print variable values when there is an error, but I also want to capture the error message. When I divide by 0 interactively, I get zsh: division by 0, but when I do it in the script I get no such error message output to stdout or stderr.
How can I get it?  Also the line number where the error occurred would be helpful.
Here is the test script:
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# Testing use of trap to print variables for diagnosis
# if script fails

set -o err_return
trap err.diagnostics EXIT

function err.diagnostics {
    DATE=$(date +"%A, %b %d, %H:%M:%S")
    printf '**************\n %s \n There has been an error \n Current variable values follow \n************** \n' $DATE
    printf ' A: %f \n B: %d \n C: %f \n D: %d \n Z: %d \n' $A $B $C $D $Z
}

function do_stuff {
    A=1.2
    B=2
    Z=0
    (( C = A + B ))
    (( D = C / Z ))
}

do_stuff

The output is:
jim@Tabernacle:~/ > test.zsh
**************
 Friday, May 24, 12:39:41 
 There has been an error 
 Current variable values follow 
************** 
 A: 1.200000 
 B: 2 
 C: 3.200000 
 D: -9223372036854775808 
 Z: 0 

** EDIT **
For anyone who doesn't believe there is no error when dividing by zero, here is a minimal reproducible example. No error when the dividend is a float.
#!/usr/bin/zsh
(( A = 5.2 / 0 ))
echo $?
echo $A


but when I do it in the script I get no such error message output to stdout or stderr : I don't believe you here. I did this simple experiment: ((5/0)) 2>/dev/null. This does not show any error message, but without the redirection, we see the error. From this, we conclude that the error message is indeed written to stderr. Show a minimal reproducible example which demonstrates your point!

@user1934428, see edit in original post.

Ah, I missed the fact that your dividend is a float. Your echo $A should have printed out Inf, i.e. infinity (at least this happens in my zsh version, 5.8.1). You can catch this by testing the result of the division for this string. This is consistent in behaviour with other programming languages when they do floating point division. In Ruby for instance. you would also get the Float value Infinitiy.

I think this is covered here.

Inf is fine, but why is it an error when dividend is integer, but not when it's a float?  That makes no sense to me.

Did you read the link I sent in my last comment? What are you still missing? Float division by zero is well defined by IEEE, but integer division isn't. I wasn't in the IEEE committee meetings, when they decided this, but I'm sure that they had their reasons.

I found a better way to do this that covers all errors and doesn't require appending commands with error redirections.
# Send error message both to stdout and to error file
exec 2> >(tee /tmp/spin_err >&2)
# Exit after error (error trap will run first)
set -o err_return

function err.diagnostics {
   EXIT_STATUS=$?
   . . .
}

# Handle errors with err.diagnostics function (no need to pass $?)
trap 'err.diagnostics' ZERR

. . . Rest of script

Of course it still won't handle dividing float by 0 ;-)
